# Let $A,\ B,\ C \leq V$ such that $A + C = B + C,\ A \cap C = B \cap C,\ A \subset B$. Prove $A = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I limited myself to prove $B \subset A$:

Let $j \in B + C$. Then $j = b + c,\ b\in B, c \in C$. Since $A + C = B + C$, then $j \in A + C$, $j = a + c,\ a\in A, c \in C$, so $a + c = b + c \Rightarrow a = b \in A$, which completes the proof.

I don't seem to need the fact that $A \cap C = B \cap C$, am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: $j = b + c = a + \tilde{c}$, you have to prove that $c = \tilde{c}$

Comment: You denote different elements of $C$ by the same letter $c$ and then treat them as the same element.

Comment: Oh, that's correct. I didn't realize that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You have proved that $B+C=A+C$, but that's already among the assumptions.

You want to take $b\in B$ and show that $b\in A$.

Since $B\subset B+C=A+C$, you can write $b=a+c$ for some $a\in A$ and $c\in C$. But then $c=b-a\in B$, due to $A\subset B$.

This implies $c\in B\cap C$. Can you finish?

---

More generally, the lattice $L(V)$ of subspaces of a vector space is *modular*, that is, it satisfies

> for all $A,B,C\in L(V)$, if $A\subset B$, then $A+(B\cap C)=(A+C)\cap B$

In your case $A+(B\cap C)=A+(A\cap C)=A$ and $(A+C)\cap B=(B+C)\cap B=B$.

You should try and prove the above *modular identity*.

Comment: Ok. So far, I've concluded that $A + (A \cap C) \subseteq A$, so given that $(B + C) \cap B = B$, then $B \subseteq A$ follows instantly, right?

Comment: @EduardoV.Kuri Yes, but $A+(A\cap C)=A$ is really obvious.

Comment: Always my best regards